Jenkins service has no permissions
I'm running Jenkins as a windows service. In one of my build pipelines, I want to build an Android app with gradle and copy it to a network drive.
I've written a C# script/console app to make some versioning and after that it should copy the apk to the network drive, but when it comes to the "File.Copy(..)" line I get an exception

"Permission denied".

The service is running as a AD user called "Jenkins" which has admin rights and definitely access to the network drives. When I call that script manually, logged in as "Jenkins" on that machine, it works fine, but when that program is called by Jenkins it seems to have no permission.
What I've tried:
The Jenkins service is running as Jenkins user, I've checked all permissions of the network folders and gave the Jenkins user explicitly access to that folders.
What is causing Jenkins to have no permission, although it runs as a user which has admin rights?
Thanks in advance

are you building on the master node?`or is it spinning up containers that don't get the credentials?

Yes, I'm just using the master node running on the same windows machine where the jenkins service runs.

if you make a simple jenkins pipeline with a simple command to access the network share, does that fail too?

Yes, I made a test pipeline which just runs a script to copy something to the network drive, it fails.

and does a whoami in that script return the same as in the console?
